# Qual a diferença entre usar className, classList.toggle() e classList.add()?

Tags: javascript, html

Testei e o resultado deu o mesmo usando a propriedade `className` e o método `classList.toggle`:

- Então qual a vantagem e desvantagem de usar?

Usando o `className`:

```
var btnSignin = document.querySelector("#signin");
var btnSignup = document.querySelector("#signup");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
      
btnSignin.addEventListener("click", function () {
  body.className = "sign-in-js"; 
});
    
btnSignup.addEventListener("click", function () {
  body.className = "sign-up-js";
});
```

Usando o `classList.toggle()`:

```
var btnSignin = document.querySelector("#signin");
var btnSignup = document.querySelector("#signup"); 
var body = document.querySelector("body");
    
btnSignin.addEventListener("click", function () {
  body.classList.toggle("sign-up-js");
});
    
btnSignup.addEventListener("click", function () {
  body.classList.toggle("sign-up-js");
});
```

Comment: Veja a documentação de ambos [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/className) e  [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Answer (score 4):

A propriedade `className` é uma string que contém **todas** as classes de um elemento. Por exemplo:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(el.className); //=> foo bar baz

// Se modificarmos a classe utilizando `className`,
// pode-se acabar perdendo todas as anteriores. Veja:
el.className = 'qux';

console.log(el.className); //=> qux
```

```html
<div class="foo bar baz">...</div>
```

Desse modo, verifica-se que `className` nada mais é do que uma simples propriedade do tipo string que corresponde diretamente ao atributo `class` de um elemento. Você pode adicionar uma classe utilizando operador `+=`, por exemplo, mas quando precisa *alterar* uma classe ou *remover* uma classe pode ficar um pouco mais complicado.

Já o método `toggle` pertence ao objeto `classList` de um elemento. Ele irá inserir a classe caso não exista e remover caso exista.

Um exemplo:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(el.className); //=> foo bar baz

// Irá remover a classe `bar`, uma vez que já existe.
el.classList.toggle('bar');

console.log(el.className); //=> foo baz

// Irá adicionar a classe `bar`, uma vez que não existe.
el.classList.toggle('bar');

console.log(el.className); //=> foo baz bar
```

```html
<div class="foo bar baz">...</div>
```

Além de `toggle`, o objeto `classList` possui vários outros métodos de "conveniência" para o manejo de classes, como `classList.add` ou `classList.remove`. Não existe comparação direta entre `className` e `classList.toggle`, já que desempenham funções diferentes.

Consulte a documentação para saber mais:

- [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/className)
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)